# How to evaluate a string to make it a TS import path?

Tags: node.js, typescript, string, import, path

Considering the simple function below:

```
import * as fr_index from "../locales/index/fr.json"

export const translate = (key: string, from: string) => {

  console.log(fr_index.greeting)   // hello world

  console.log(from)                // fr_index
  console.log(key)                 // greeting
  console.log(from.key)            // undefined <-- Problem
  console.log(from[key])           // undefined <-- Problem
}
```

How to evaluate `from.key` to display `hello world`?
I've tried with `path` and/or `eval()` without success. Thx.

Comment: @cmgchess Already tried ; doesn't work. I've updated my question.

Comment: yeah my bad i didnt read properly and later saw the from. `eval(from)[key]` eval is bad btw

Comment: It works. Thx. Any alternative without eval()?

Comment: nothing comes to mind other than `fr_index[key]`

Comment: @cmgchess In fact, it doesn't work with `eval(from)[key]` if I have not `console.log(fr_index.greeting)` => `ReferenceError: fr_index is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below works but seems ugly.

```
import * as fr_index from '../locales/index/fr.json'
import * as en_index from '../locales/index/en.json'
import * as de_index from '../locales/index/de.json'
import * as it_index from '../locales/index/it.json'
... all i18n files

export const translate = (key: string, from: string) => {
  fr_index; en_index; de_index; it_index   // mandatory
  return eval(from)[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as fr_index from '../locales/index/fr.json'
import * as en_index from '../locales/index/en.json'
import * as de_index from '../locales/index/de.json'
import * as it_index from '../locales/index/it.json'

const DataSheet = {
  fr_index,
  en_index,
  de_index,
  it_index,
} as const

export const translate = <F extends keyof typeof DataSheet, K extends keyof typeof DataSheet[F]>(
    from: F, key: K
) => {
    return DataSheet[from][key]
}
let s = translate('fr_index', 'greeting')
//  ^?
// let s: "hello world"
```

Comment: You don't need dynamic imports, do you?

Comment: In fact I do. The function is for translating/i18n my app.
I need to import ALL json content (not just `greeting`) and depending on a value in a cookie load `fr_index`, `en_index`, `cn_index`...

Comment: @charnould I can either make the function `async` or list all the files imports, which one is better?

Comment: in my mind I'll list all import JSON (I've updated my second post)

Comment: @charnould my answer will work, all you need is to list all ones in DataSheet